# select some data from one database table and insert into another table in the same database

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna select some column from one table (`oldDataTable`) and insert into another table (`newDataTable`). Both are in the same database. I tried. If i choose only one column it works. But if i choose more than one column nothing happens.

oldDataTable has columns like

```
Name | Date | Voltage | Current | Power | RMS.
```

I just wanna select columns like `Name| Date| Power` and insert it into `newDataTable`. I am doing this when user submit a form button. Any help please.

````
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  include ("DBconnect.php");
  $conn= mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db );
  if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  else{
    $insertNEQuery= "INSERT INTO newDataTable (Name, Date, Power) SELECT (Name, Date, Power) FROM oldDataTable WHERE ID = '2' ";
    //it should be a bunch of rows. I have data for every one minute. 

    mysqli_query($conn, $insertNEQuery);
    echo " data updated!";
    $conn->close();
  }
} else 
    echo " please click submit button!";
?>
```
````

Comment: Not sure - but try it without brackets in `SELECT ()`

Comment: @NigelRen that is indeed the issue, it will cause `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` errors

Comment: @NigelRen That worked like champ. Thanks mate ...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses is not required in the `SELECT`, the following query will work.

```
INSERT INTO newDataTable (Name, Date, Power) 
SELECT Name, Date, Power FROM oldDataTable WHERE ID = '2'
```

So your code will be:

```
$insertNEQuery= "INSERT INTO newDataTable (Name, Date, Power) SELECT Name, Date, Power FROM oldDataTable WHERE ID = '2' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
INSERT INTO newDataTable (SELECT Name, Date, Power FROM oldDataTable WHERE ID = '2')";
```